# spelling: αs or α-s, when referring to alphas as in more than one alpha?

Tags: orthography

When referring the more than one alpha, is the correct spelling αs or α-s?

Comment: What has your research told you? And what remains unclear to you? Have you found any indication anywhere that hyphens are ever used to form plurals anywhere?

Comment: What's the context? Are you literally talking about the Greek letter alpha (in a sentence like, "The Greek word for 'wood' contains two alphas"), or are you talking about something commonly denoted with that letter (in a sentence like, "The two wheels have the same angular velocity at time zero, but different angular accelerations")?

Comment: My research told me, that I am unable to formulate a relevant google search  about this question. I found some examples where NOT to use a hyphen, but they didn't cover this specific case of trying to put a symbol into plural.

Comment: @ruakh The latter.

Comment: **α-s** strikes me as blindingly unlikely. The choice between **αs** and **α's** is essentially a matter of personal preference and/or your chosen style guide, but I'd certainly use an apostrophe in this specific case, to avoid confusion with **as** (depending on what typeface you're using, and how sharp-eyed you expect your reader to be). But I *don't* normally include that apostrophe in things like *the early 1900s*, or *CDs and DVDs*.

Comment: My _personal_ preference is to try to avoid the need in the first place - "The Greek word for 'wood' contains two alphas (α)."

Comment: I would second Jeff Zeitlin and also follow ruakh's tack.  If you're talking about the letter, say "alphas", and in a technical context where it might need to be distinguished from capital Alpha, just talk directly about e.g. "angular accelerations" instead of the variable name.  If you're having such a hard time deciding how to pluralize that you _ask StackExchange_ instead of just choosing one or the other, you seem to acknowledge that the notation is confusing.  Instead of looking for the "correct" single-letter plural, just sidestep the issue, because it could confuse your reader too.